# Missing required parameters error thrown while updating the category .how can i solve it?

Tags: laravel

**    Missing required parameters for [Route: Category.edit] [URI: Category/{Category}/edit].**

```
public function edit( $category)
{
     $category=Category::find($category);
     return view('admin.editcategory',compact('category'));
}


    public function update(Request $request ,Category $category)
    {
        $category->update($this->validateRequest());
          return redirect()->route('Category.edit');
    }

    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('Category.update',['category'=>$category])}}" method="POST">

     @method('PATCH')
                                <input type="text" name="category_name" value="{{$category->category_name}}">
                                <input type="number" name="category_based_no_of_rooms" value="{{$category->category_based_no_of_rooms}}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit category</button>


                              @csrf
                            </form>
```

Comment: that route requires a parameter and you are not passing one when generating the redirect to that route ...

Comment: can you give me the solution?

Comment: Can you show me your route then i'll definately give you the solution

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes  there you go ... the docs are your friend :)

Comment: i have used resource controller

Comment: Can you show your route? from web file

Comment: I think If your route is **Route::resource('category,'ResourceController')**  then your form action should be **action="{{route('category.update',['category'=>$category])}}**

Answer (score 0):

**public function update(Category $category)**

**[URI: Category/{Category}/edit].**

you did not added your second parameter in your mcontroller method -> edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass category in second argument.

```
public function update(Request $request ,Category $category)
{
    $category->update($this->validateRequest());
      return redirect()->route('Category.edit', ['category' => $category]);
}
```

For more details have look on this:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redirects